# Is this relation between conditional distributions on a common space true?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $(\Omega, P)$ be a probability space. If $F$ is a sigma algebra on $\Omega$ (contained in the ambient sigma algebra, of course) then I'll write $P_F$ for the conditional probability of $P$ on $F$, i.e. $P_F(\omega)$ is a probability measure on $\Omega$.

We have by definition

$$P\cdot P_G=P$$

where by $\cdot$ I mean the application of the transition kernel $P_G$ to $P$. Let $F$ be some other sigma algebra. Do we have

$$P_F(\omega)\cdot P_G=P_F(\omega)\quad \omega\text{-a.e. ?}$$

I think the answer is yes. If we call the write hand side $f(\omega)$, then by definition $f(\omega)$ is a probability measure on $\Omega$ and I think I can show that $f(\omega)(A)$ is $F$-measurable for all $A$. Is that correct, and does that establish the identity?

Comment: Generally $\omega$ denotes *elements* of $\Omega$, while a probability measure on $\Omega$ would assign probabilities to *events,* e.g. sets in the "ambient" $\sigma$-algebra (or sub-$\sigma$-algebras). So the notation $P_F(\omega)$ is a bit peculiar.

Comment: @Math1000 $P_F(\omega)$ is a probability measure. That is, $P_F$ is a function assigning measures to points of $\Omega$. You would have to write $P_F(\omega)(A)$ if you wanted to evaluate it at the event $A$.

Comment: @JackM But in general $P_F(\omega)$ may not be a probability measure. It may not even be a probability measure with probability $1$. (That's not to say that Math1000's comment is on point---it's not.) Also, there seems to be some mixups with the $F$s and $G$s.